# How do I calculate the amount of sunlight a planet gets?

Tags: science-based, planets, sunlight

I'm working on a planet and I want to know what is the maximum amount of sunlight my planet gets in lux (for Earth It's 120000 lux).

My planet orbits an M4V class red dwarf that has a mass of 0.22 M☉, radius of 0.16 R☉ and a temperature of 3000 K. The planet's semi-major axis is 2.3 AU.

Please also include the formula or program you used to calculate the answer. If you need any additional info I'll add it.

Comment: Your requirement of lux makes this complicated. Calculating radiative flux is simple math, but luminous flux depends on the interplay of the stars spectrum and human eye.

Comment: Yeah what b.Lorenz said, I can give you the stellar luminosity very easily but the next bit is a lot more problematic.

Comment: Also, because you have a planet orbiting a red dwarf (smaller than sun) further than the distance that mars is from, it is likely (read: certain) that the planet is too cold for liquid water to form on. So, if you want life, move it a lot closer (my estimate is about 10-20 times closer)

Comment: Based on this question and its answers I think it should be moved to Physics SE.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Calculating flux

I think a slightly more helpful quantity to calculate is the *flux* received by the planet - the power per unit area from the star. The mean flux on Earth is the [solar constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solar_constant), $F_e=1.36\times10^3\text{ W m}^{-2}$. If a planet orbits a star of luminosity $L_*$ at a distance $r_p$, the flux received is
$$F_p=\frac{L_*}{4\pi r_p^2}$$
The ratio of the planet's flux $F_p$ to the solar constant $F_e$ is
$$\frac{F_p}{F_e}=\frac{L_*}{L_{\odot}}\left(\frac{r_p}{1\text{ AU}}\right)^{-2}$$
For an M4V dwarf, I'd expect $L_*\approx0.006L_{\odot}$. Plugging this in, we get
$$F_p=1.1\times10^{-3}F_e=1.50\text{ W m}^{-2}$$
for an M4V star.

Why should we use flux instead of lux?

- It's easier to calculate. And when I say easier, I mean *much* easier. [Lux is a lot more complicated.](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/135618/56299)
- It's great for calculating things like the effective temperature of a planet.
- It's *much* more commonly used in this sort of scenario.

I used [stellar models by Eric Mamajek](http://www.pas.rochester.edu/%7Eemamajek/EEM_dwarf_UBVIJHK_colors_Teff.txt) to find the star's luminosity - he gives a $\log L_*/L_{\odot}=-2.2$, so $L_*\approx0.006L_{\odot}$. It's worth noting that those models list an M4V star as having $T_{eff}\approx3200\text{ K}$ and $R\approx0.258R_{\odot}$ - so this is based on those figures. Using your numbers (which are for a smaller, cooler star) and the Stefan-Boltzmann law, I get $L_*\approx0.00186L_{\odot}$, leading to a flux of $F_p\approx0.48\text{ W m}^{-2}$. I believe your values are slightly off for the given spectral type.

I've written [a Python program](https://github.com/HDE226868/Binary-habitability/blob/master/flux.py) to calculate the flux received on a planet based on a given spectral type, using those models. It should be a quick shortcut for you in the future.

## Astronomical lux

[It's claimed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Illuminance#Astronomy) that you can convert between a star's apparent magnitude in the V-band ($m_V$) and its illuminance ($I_V$) - the value I think you're looking for. Wikipedia's formula is
$$I_V=10^{(-14.18-m_V)/2.5}$$
which matches values from [the National Park Service](https://www.nps.gov/subjects/nightskies/science.htm). The absolute magnitude of an M4V star is - according to the same stellar models - $M_V\approx12.80$. Apparent magnitude can be calculated from absolute magnitude by
$$m_V=M_V+5\log\left(\frac{r_p}{10\text{ parsecs}}\right)$$
Putting this together for our case yields $m_V\approx-16.96$, and, finally, we get $I_V\approx12.7\text{ lux}$.

Comment: Calculated luminosity for the OP's star is actually .002 solar luminosity, according to [this calculator](https://www.omnicalculator.com/physics/luminosity) anyway.

Comment: @Ash I tend to use a specific grid of stellar models - I assume various ones differ by a factor of maybe two or three. An M5V dwarf is listed as being at $\approx0.003L_*$; the value is sensitive to the exact choice of spectral type.

Comment: Yeah based on that data set it looks like the given spectral type and the specifications are incompatible.

Comment: @Ash Ah, fair point. I've added in additional numbers based on the OP's specifications.

Comment: You are right. Lux is only useful to determine how bright the sky would seem to human eyes. Any other derivative effect - solar cell power, plant life, weather... depends on radiative flux.

Comment: For some reason the .py file closes immediately after opening.

Comment: @i_am_a_smart It's possible I haven't set it up correctly; until I can figure out if something's wrong, copying-and-pasting might be your best bet. Sorry for the problems!